# Opening :help into an existing window/split

Tags: vim

I currently have my terminal running in full screen, with three nice large vertical splits in it. The leftmost is running NERDTree, so I don't really need the full height. I'd like to split that column horizontally and put help in the new frame, but when I `:help`, it creates a large horizontal split across the entire screen. I know I can technically set this up the way I want before I make my vertical splits, but I tend to not think about opening help until I'm well into my workflow.

So is it possible to have help only split the existing window, or open into the current buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (works for me) is:

```
:above help
```

Note that it already has the same behaviour if you were in the rightmost column.

See also `:help vert`, `:help above` etc. for all kinds of variations (rightbelow etc.)